# How to restore Sticker's stickiness?

Tags: substitute-tool, stationery, office-supplies, adhesive, packaging

I have some old stickers from my collection that are almost fallen off of their backing paper. I was wondering if there's a decent way to restore them and they would still be stickers (would be able to peel them off of paper and apply to whatever surface). Any suggestions?

Comment: Would you be averse to something permanent?

Comment: If there would not be any proper way to do it then yes.

Comment: so your goal is to make them sticky, then put them back on the backing paper to continue to hold onto them? are the backs still clean?

Comment: Why can you not use the glassine hinges that are made for this kind of collection to attach stickers into albums? They are water-soluable, and inexpensive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This may not be a life hack as it describes using an adhesive agent, but it is a great fix for the sticker problem. I am not certain it was designed to fix stickers so this may still be a hack... but nonetheless, here is my answer:

Elmer's makes a "[rubber cement](http://elmers.com/product/detail/E904)" which is basically a contact cement. I have used this to create stickers out of normal paper before, but never as a solution to "fix" old stickers.

Basically you apply the adhesive to the sticker an allow it to dry. you can then apply a second coat to the backing paper and allow this to dry. once they are both dry you can attach them to one another and the bond will hold.

With my home-made stickers I haven't had the need to remove them from the original surface, short of repositioning them when being first placed. I would assume that since I was able to readjust and have the sticker affix itself in the new position with ease, that you would be able to use this method to make a non-permanent sticker fixer solution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately thera are no such items in my area to buy (I'm from outside US). What about the glue that's designed for bicycle tire puncture repair? Is it similar?

Comment: amazon sells it and ships it globally I believe... http://www.amazon.com/b?node=12900041 As far as the cement for bike tires, that bond is a much stronger fixative and most likely will not allow for future removal. it is a bonding cement.

Answer (score 3):

To actually make a sticker sticky again without using any kind of tape, the easiest way I found would be using a spray adhesive, as shown [here](http://www.ehow.com/how_4967323_make-stickers-sticky-again.html).

Another solution would be double-sided tape. But since that is fairly expensive you could stick (pun intended) to plain clear tape. Just roll a piece of clear tape (size depending on size of the sticker) into a loop with the sticky side on the outer side. Then attach this loop to your sticker and then stick it to the surface you want your sticker on. I personally use this "clear-tape-loop" anytime I want to stick something not that heavy somewhere.

If you want to remove the sticker sometime later I would stay away from any kind of glue (super glue, glue sticks, etc.) since those will leave glue residues. I actually didn't try the spray adhesive method myself, so I can't tell if it will leave residue as well.

Answer (score 2):

Use Eclectic Products, Inc.'s "E6000 Extreme Tack" repositionable glue. I've been using it on paper scrapbooking stickers that do not stick to my matte-finish painted interior walls (paper-on-paper adhesives are notoriously weak) with total success. Extremely sticky, dries clear, not very expensive, comes off without staining, repositionable (as the label says), and available on Amazon as well as other websites. Use sparingly as directed and you will be pleased with the results.

Answer (score 0):

Rinse the sticky part with water, then wait 30-50 minutes for it to dry, all done!

Comment: Welcome to Lifehacks! This sounds great but can you add some more detail? Thanks!